# Is there a REGEXP_LIKE equivalent function in Apache Drill?

Tags: apache-drill

Anything in Drill which can be similar to:

`REGEXP_LIKE ( <COLUMN>, <REGULAR_EXPRESSION< ) RETURNS BOOLEAN` ?

Answer (score 2):

The following code should mimic REGEXP_LIKE in drill. Just make sure to replace '1' with a text string that does not occur in the column and that the regular expression captures the entire string (by appending .*) .

```
SELECT CASE WHEN REGEXP_REPLACE(<COLUMN>, <REGULAR_EXPRESSION>,'1') = '1' THEN true ELSE false END
```

Answer (score 0):

`REGEXP_LIKE` is not supported as per drill [docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/string-manipulation/).

If you can proceed with wildcard, you can check [**ILIKE**](https://drill.apache.org/docs/string-manipulation/#ilike).

```
ILIKE ( <COLUMN>, <VALUE> ) RETURNS BOOLEAN
```

Sample command:

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE ILIKE(name, '%DEV%')"
```

You can ask the [community](https://drill.apache.org/mailinglists/) if somebody has written any UDF for this.

Or you can write your own UDF for this function. Check drill [docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/develop-custom-functions-introduction/) for details of writing a UDF.